# Split an array into equal contiguous subarrays of equal sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to check if it's possible to split an array into contiguous sub-arrays which have the same sum. Splitting the array means also to remove the border elements of it.

For example, to split it in 3 parts we need to remove to elements

```
myArray = [2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3]
                 ^        ^
```

by removing that 2 elements there are 3 contiguous sub-arrays of same sum `[2, 4]`, `[3, 3]` and `[2, 1, 3]`.

So if it's possible to split the array into 3 parts (with equal sum) and remove the borders between them - it should return true, otherwise it should return false.

An example that would return `false` is `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. Because after removing 2 elements it will have 4 elements of `1` which cannot be grouped in 3 equal sums

I don't know how to approach this problem, any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: do you want to get `true` or the new array? do you have sonme other examples?

Comment: @NinaScholz  I want to get `true` if the operation I've described can be done in that input array. I added an example that should return `false`

Comment: How much element you can remove? Only 2?

Comment: @Soham yes, only 2. and that 2 elements must be the borders of the newly created subarrays, as in the first example I wrote in the question

Comment: Without a runtime complexity requirement, or memory constraints, there's a super simple answer and that's just "try all permutations and return true if you find a single valid segmentation". So before folks try to answer you: did you implement that first, to see whether that works _for your needs_ rather than in general? (after all, for short inputs, high order complexity is typically still fast enough)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the values from left and right side and if equal get the sum of the rest and check if this value is equal to one of the side.

If not add one value to the left side.

```js
function check(array) {
    var i = 0,
        j = array.length - 1,
        left = array[i++],
        right = array[j--];

    while (i < j) {
        if (left < right) { left += array[i++]; continue; }
        if (left > right) { right += array[j--]; continue; }
        if (array.slice(i + 1, j).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) === left) return true;
        left += array[i++];
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(check([2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3]));
console.log(check([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: as i read the question, op wants always three parts and two elements to separate the groups.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this.

```js
myArray = [2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3];
var x = []; //result if sub-arrays

var i = 0;

while(i< myArray.length-3){
 x.push([myArray[i],myArray[i+1]])
  i = i+3;
  
};


var a =[]; //remaining element
for(var k =i; k<myArray.length;k++){
   a.push(myArray[k]);

}
 x.push(a)

console.log(x);
var sum =x[0].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var returnTrue = true;
for(var k=1; k<x.length; k++){
  var sumAnother = x[k].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  if(sumAnother!== sum){
    returnTrue = false;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(returnTrue);
```